# vb6 app hangs during long time operation on XP

Tags: multithreading, winforms, vb6

I have a VB6 app which executes a long operation. Let's say, saving into database takes more than 1 minute.

While this saving lasts I want my window be locked (disabled) and hourglass cursor shown.

But next code doesn't do this:

```
Private Sub Update_Click()
    Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass
    Me.MousePointer = vbHourglass
    Me.Enabled = False
    'This takes more than minute:
    Update
    Me.MousePointer = vbDefault
    Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault
    Me.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

I.e. form still enabled, no hourglass cursor. And if I'm trying to do anything with form, it's hangs.

Any ideas how to make the app be user-friendly and let users know that app do something after button pressed?

Unfortunately I can use only VB6 so I can't use background worker.

**NOTE**: In Win7 computer the same code makes the cursor hourglass, so the user see that app is doing something. In XP system the app simply hangs, nothing happens with cursor.

Comment: I think you've got the property `Form.Enabled` which you can set as false when your operation is being executed.

Comment: "Me.Enabled = False" already here. If i'm not mistaken Me - it's a form

Comment: Yep, so why don't you use it?

Answer (score 0):

You should add DoEvents before the update so windows forms can update the form to its new state.

DoEvents gives windows the time to handle pending events.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Me.Refresh` after `Me.Enabled = False`

This will force the form to process any outstanding events